# How we can have divider height equal to another child of horizontal stack in SWIFT UI widgets

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

Like as attached screen the divider should need to have same height of Labe; 'One Touch and price'. Here One Touch and price label is one vertical stack and this is horizontal stack to the divider.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Divider()
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4352941176, blue: 0.3803921569, alpha: 1)))
            .padding(.leading, 16.0)
            .frame(minWidth: 4, idealWidth: 4, maxWidth: 4, minHeight: 40, idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible approach - to use overlay that gives same height as parent view.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Some long label text having word wrapping").font(.headline)
            Text("Some short")
        }.padding(.leading)
    }
    .overlay(
        Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 4), // << your divider here !!
        alignment: .leading
    )
    .frame(width: 300) // just for wrap demo
}
```